# How to run mocha test for different environments from the command line

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I have created some API tests using mocha and supertest, I need to run the tests in different environments(different environments have different baseUrl, APIKey, admin username, password Etc)
is that possible I can pass the different environments by using CL

like Cypress did
e.g.

```
"scripts": {
    "cy:run:preview": "cypress run --env configFile=preview",
},
```